# Torque Required for spinning tube

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm trying to spec a stepper motor that would allow me to position a tube, as well as spin the tube continuously in either direction. Ideally at a maximum of 60rpm, but variable speed which be ideal.

The tube would be held in the middle. It is 1035mm long and has a 42mm diameter and weighs 1kg.

What are the calculations I would need to be able to work this out please?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rotation at 60rpm creates air drag. It is kind of turbulent and not linear, due to rotation, but we just consider the simple version.

$Fd = 1/2C_d  ρ v^2 A \quad \text{for a bar moving into wind perpendicular to long axis}$

because of rotation the speed hence the drag changes from 0 to $(1.035/2 *2 \pi)/s$ and an average of Va= 1.035pi/s.

Assuming a $Cd=0.6 and \rho= 1.2kg/m^3 $ and assuming average drag = 1/2 max Fd

$F_d= 1/2*0.6*1.2*1.01*0.042 \pi^2=0.6/4*1.2*0.042*1.01 \pi^2 *0.50015=0.0376kg \quad \text{at 60RPM}$

This force works at 2/3*L/2, So torque is,

$  \tau= 2/3* 0.5015*0.0375= 0.0126kgm=0.123 Nm$

This torque should be enough to position the bar and rotate it at a maximum of 60 RPM. you can add more if you need a more agile system.
check my numbers, please.